# Get row that changed with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

In my app I have a binding list to hold data from my table like session and use `SqlTableDependency` to detect change and update that binding list.

Binding list code that holds data from the database:

```
private static BindingList<DAL.Product> _products;
public static BindingList<DAL.Product> Products
{
    get
    {

        if (_products == null)
        {
            using (var db = new DAL.dbDataContext())
            {
                _products = new BindingList<DAL.Product>(db.Products.ToList());
            }
            DB_Watcher.Products = new TableDependency.SqlClient.SqlTableDependency<DAL.Product>(Properties.Settings.Default.My_Sale_DBConnectionString);
            DB_Watcher.Products.OnChanged += DB_Watcher.Products_Changed;
            DB_Watcher.Products.Start();
        }
        return _products;
    }
}
```

`SqlTableDependency` code that detects changes in the database and updates my list"

```
public static SqlTableDependency<DAL.Product> Products;
public static void Products_Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<DAL.Product> e)
{
    Application.OpenForms[0].Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {

        if (e.ChangeType == ChangeType.Insert)
        {
            Session.Products.Add(e.Entity);
        }
        else if (e.ChangeType == ChangeType.Update)
        {
            var Index = Session.Products.IndexOf(Session.Products.Single(x => x.ID == e.Entity.ID));
            Session.Products.Remove(Session.Products.Single(x => x.ID == e.Entity.ID));
            Session.Products.Insert(Index, e.Entity);
        }
        else if (e.ChangeType == ChangeType.Delete)
        {
            Session.Products.Remove(Session.Products.Single(x => x.ID == e.Entity.ID));
        }
    }));
```

But I moved from LinQ2SQL to Entity Framework and `SqlTableDependency` has some issues with like `SqlTableDependency` doesn't support column type `Image`.

My question is, how to detect changes like I do but with Entity Framework?

Comment: Probably by changing your column to type `varbinary(max)` since `image` is no longer supported. Are you seeing any other issues?

Comment: @DaleK Thanks for the edit, English is not my native language, I can use your suggestion but is there any way to do this with EF directly?